# Deleting an HttpCookie Not Just Its Value

Tags: javascript, cookies, model-view-controller, httpcookie

Using MVC

I am creating a cookie on login like the following:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("UserId", Id))
```

I searched for ways to delete cookies so I can use it on Logout, and I found this:

```
 If Response.Cookies("UserId") IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim c = New HttpCookie("UserId")
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
                Response.Cookies.Add(c)
 End If

 Response.Cookies.Clear()
```

And on Client side I am doing the following:

```
 document.cookie = "access_token=";
```

But I figured out this doesn't delete the cookie, it just empties it, I would still have a cookie called `UserId` with a value of `Nothing`.

Now if the user Logs out and logs in right after it, it's causing me problems.

What I want to do, is completely delete the Cookie with the name `UserId` , Completely erase it from the browser cookies, not just empty its value.

Is there any way to do that?

**Edit**

I think the problem is with this part:

```
If Response.Cookies("UserId") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim c = New HttpCookie("UserId")
```

Because when I debug this code, after this line, **The count of Response.Cookies I get is 2**  , means it's creating 2 cookies with the same name and getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

you missed `expires`, for example:

```
document.cookie="access_token=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: Can't I just set document.cookie=""; in Javascript? Wouldnt that delete the cookie and not just its value?

Comment: document.cookie acts as property with getter and setter. When you read, it returns all cookies. When you write it create or modify cookie. Passing empty string will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("cookie name")
```

But you cannot directly delete a cookie, you have to set it to expire before the current date like an example:

```
 myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

Comment: Can I set the expiry to -1 days and remove it right after it in the same controller?

Comment: You can check first with the first code alone because it works fine.. but recommendation is to use the expiry date with the cookie